# Why is this nested macro replacement failing?

Tags: c, macros, initialization, c-preprocessor

I am trying to apply the [X Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635851/real-world-use-of-x-macros) concept, in order to have the possibility to initialize all struct members to a custom default (invalid) value. I write the following code:

```
#define LIST_OF_STRUCT_MEMBERS_foo \
    X(a) \
    X(b) \
    X(c)

#define X(name) int name;
struct foo {
     LIST_OF_STRUCT_MEMBERS_foo
};
#undef X


#define X(name) -1,
static inline void foo_invalidate(struct foo* in) {
     *in = (struct foo){
     LIST_OF_STRUCT_MEMBERS_foo
     };
}
#undef X

#define X(name) -1,
#define foo_DEFAULT_VALUE  { LIST_OF_STRUCT_MEMBERS_foo }
#undef X

static struct foo test = foo_DEFAULT_VALUE;
```

However, when I run the preprocessor, the definition of `foo_DEFAULT_VALUE` fails to substitute the `X(name)` calls with `-1,`

Preprocessor output:

```
struct foo {
     int a; int b; int c;
};

static inline void foo_invalidate(struct foo* in) {
     *in = (struct foo){
     -1, -1, -1, /*Here the substitution worked nicely*/
     };
}

static struct foo test = { X(a) X(b) X(c) }; /*Why this substitution failed?*/
```

I thought [C-macros could refer to other macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972785/can-a-c-macro-definition-refer-to-other-macros). Do you know why that substitution fails? Is there any workaround?

I could live with `foo_invalidate`, but I am reluctant to give up one step from having a value to be used directly at initialization.

Comment: You have `X(name)` defined to `-1,` around the `#define` for `foo_DEFAULT_VALUE`, but not where you actually *use* it.  You need the `X` macro defined where the substitution occurs, around the `static struct foo test = foo_DEFAULT_VALUE;` line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's pretend that we are the preprocessor and encountering the line:

```
static struct foo test = foo_DEFAULT_VALUE;
```

Pass 1:

```
static struct foo test = { LIST_OF_STRUCT_MEMBERS_foo };
```

Pass 2:

```
static struct foo test = { X(a) X(b) X(c) };
```

Pass 3:  Nothing to expand as `X` is undefined on this line.

---

One workaround could be defining a const variable (possibly but not necessarily `static`) to be used as default value:

```
#define X(name) -1,
static const struct foo foo_DEFAULT_VALUE = { LIST_OF_STRUCT_MEMBERS_foo };
#undef X
```

Which generates:

```
static const struct foo foo_DEFAULT_VALUE = { -1, -1, -1, };
```

Comment: What could be a workaround? I have thought about the following, but I wonder if it is optimal: `#define X(name) -1,
#define foo_DEFAULT_VALUE_GENERATOR  { LIST_OF_STRUCT_MEMBERS_foo }
static const struct foo_DEFAULT_VALUE = foo_DEFAULT_VALUE_GENERATOR;
#undef X`

Comment: Well, the straight forward way would be apparently that. Move the `#undef` after the line with the declaration. Otherwise a redesign would be needed.

Comment: @Antonio `X` doesn't even need to be defined where `foo_DEFAULT_VALUE_GENERATOR` is defined, as long as it's defined where it's used.

Comment: Instead of defining `foo_DEFAULT_VALUE` as a macro expanding to an initializer, you could declare it as a `const struct foo` *with* initializer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yep, does my edit match with what you said?

Comment: Yes, @Antonio, though personally, I wouldn't bother with the `foo_DEFAULT_VALUE_GENERATOR` macro, either, since you won't be able to use it later.  I'd just put its replacement text directly into the declaration of `foo_DEFAULT_VALUE`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Excuse me, I have removed the code in the second part of the answer because it does not work for the same reason the code in the question doesn't work

Comment: @Antonio Ow.. right. I've confused myself, sorry :) Should always test it.

Answer (score 4):

You might like the undef-free version of X_Macros,
it reduces the necessary care taken with defining and undefining around each use
and is better suited for definition in a header und useage in multiple code files:

```
#define LIST_OF_STRUCT_MEMBERS_foo(mode) \  
    X_##mode(a) \  
    X_##mode(b) \  
    X_##mode(c)  

#define X_struct(name) int name;  
#define X_list(name) -1,  
#define foo_DEFAULT_VALUE  { LIST_OF_STRUCT_MEMBERS_foo(list) }  

struct foo {  
     LIST_OF_STRUCT_MEMBERS_foo(struct)  
};  

static inline void foo_invalidate(struct foo* in) {  
     *in = (struct foo){  
     LIST_OF_STRUCT_MEMBERS_foo(list)  
     };  
}  

static struct foo test = foo_DEFAULT_VALUE;
```

Output (gcc -E):

```
struct foo {
     int a; int b; int c;
};

static inline void foo_invalidate(struct foo* in) {
     *in = (struct foo){
     -1, -1, -1,
     };
}

static struct foo test = { -1, -1, -1, };
```

Comment: Would you believe me, if I say I invented it? I do not mean I invented it *first* (there could be others, earlier), but I did come up with it by myself.

Comment: I do believe you, I searched the subject a lot yesterday, and never came across to such an implementation! I will award you a bounty as soon as it is possible!

Comment: Hello everybody, if you know other sources for this method, please let me know. If nobody finds anything I could claim to actually have invented it **first**. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You might also try to check the output of expanded macros. If you are using gcc as a compiler, `gcc -E <filename> >> full_src.txt'` shall help. More details are here: [Seeing expanded C macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985403/seeing-expanded-c-macros)

Comment: That's exactly what I did to fill the `Preprocessor output:` section of my question